# How to handle "Go"/"Enter" keyboard button Ionic2 <ion-input>

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic2, key-events

What is the event to handle "enter" or "go" keyboard key on an input?
The input is not used within a form. So clicking on it will not "submit". I just need the event.

(Running android + Ionic 2 on Beta 11)

Comment: you have to use form `type="submit"` it worked for me

Answer (score 77):

I did like this:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" (keyup.enter)="handleLogin()"></ion-input>
```

And:

```
handleLogin() {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Is this also possible on the next button of softkeypad of android?

Comment: This works for me if the button reads "Go" but when it reads "Next" no event is fired.

Answer (score 4):

For my case, I'm not getting **next** button within a form for both Android and IOS. I'm only getting done. so I handled **done** as a **next** by using following directive.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

@Directive({
  selector: '[br-data-dependency]' // Attribute selector
})
export class BrDataDependency {
  @Output() input: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input('br-data-dependency') nextIonInputId: any = null;

  constructor(public Keyboard: Keyboard,
    public elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event) {
    if (event.srcElement.tagName !== "INPUT") {
      return;
    }

    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (code === TAB_KEY_CODE) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.onNext();
      let previousIonElementValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[0].value;
      this.input.emit(previousIonElementValue)
    } else if (code === ENTER_KEY_CODE) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.onEnter();
      let previousIonElementValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[0].value;
      this.input.emit(previousIonElementValue)
    }
  }

  onEnter() {
    console.log("onEnter()");
    if (!this.nextIonInputId) {
      return;
    }

    let nextInputElement = document.getElementById(this.nextIonInputId);

    // On enter, go to next input field
    if (nextInputElement && nextInputElement.children[0]) {
      let element: any = nextInputElement.children[0];
      if (element.tagName === "INPUT") {
        element.focus();
      }
    }
  }

  onNext() {
    console.log("onNext()");
    if (!this.nextIonInputId) {
      return;
    }

    let nextInputElement = document.getElementById(this.nextIonInputId);

    // On enter, go to next input field
    if (nextInputElement && nextInputElement.children[0]) {
      let element: any = nextInputElement.children[0];
      if (element.tagName === "INPUT") {
        element.focus();
      }
    }
  }
}

const TAB_KEY_CODE = 9;
const ENTER_KEY_CODE = 13;
```

How to use?

```
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
      <ion-input br-data-dependency="password" type="text" formControlName="username" placeholder="USERNAME" (input)="userNameChanged($event)"></ion-input>
      <ion-input id="password" password type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="PASSWORD"></ion-input>
      <button submit-button ion-button type="submit" block>Submit</button>

</form>
```

Hope this help someone!!

Edit: Let me know if you are abled to show next button for the first input box?

Comment: Nice idea Sandeep!
Does not seem you really need `import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';` - it's not used anywhere. Angular `@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])` is all what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do that might be to use Ionic2 forms. I'v found this: https://blog.khophi.co/ionic-2-forms-formbuilder-and-validation/

Otherwise - If you "just want the "Enter" event handler" this is quite complex (!) and not out of the box as you might be thinking:

HTML:

```
<ion-input id="myInput" #myInput type="submit" [(model)]="textValue" (input)="setText( $event.target.value )" placeholder="Send Message ..." autocorrect="off"></ion-input>
```

TS:

```
...
declare let DeviceUtil: any;
...
export class Component_OR_PAGE
{
    public textValue: string;
    @ViewChild( 'myInput') inputElm : ElementRef;
    @HostListener( 'keydown', ['$event'] )
        keyEvent( e )
        {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            log.d( "HostListener.keyEvent() - code=" + code );
            if( code === 13 )
            {
                log.d( "e.srcElement.tagName=" + e.srcElement.tagName );
                if( e.srcElement.tagName === "INPUT" )
                {
                    log.d( "HostListener.keyEvent() - here" );
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.onEnter();
                    DeviceUtil.closeKeyboard();
                }
            }
        };

    ...

    setText( text )
    {
        log.d( "setText() - text=" + text );
        this.textValue = text;
    }

    onEnter()
    {
        console.log( "onEnter()" );
        this.inputText.emit( this.textValue );
        this.textValue = "";
        // ionic2 beta11 has issue with data binding
        let myInput = document.getElementById( 'myInput' );
        let innerInput: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>myInput.children[0];
        innerInput.value = "";
    }
}
```

JS:

```
DeviceUtil =
{
    closeKeyboard: function()
    {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, looks a bit implicit, but really saved my time.

Comment: Agreed that forms are the "correct" way to do it. But, if you just want to call a method on "enter" ... then use the `keyup.enter` call. Also mentioned in another answer.