# Get Next button in ionic2 application input box

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-keyboard

I am having a login box which is a form, i need that when use will click on username, in keyboard next should appear but when user went to password GO should appear.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="title"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" name="pswd"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button type="submit" block>Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: was you abled to solve this problem?

Comment: See my answer to following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730477/how-to-handle-go-enter-keyboard-button-ionic2-ion-input/44198030#44198030