# How to customise "Return" button to "Done" in iOS/iphone using cordova or ionic v1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, custom-keyboard

I am developing hybrid app using ionic/Cordova. By default keyboard in iOS has "Return" Key. I wanted to customise it to "Done" or "Next". 
Since it it possible form native side. It gives us below options :
We can change "Return" into only one of these predefined labels with the returnKeyType property:

```
Return (default)
Go
Google
Join
Next
Route
Search
Send
Yahoo
Done
Emergency Call
Continue (as of iOS 9)
```

How we can do it using ionic v1/ Cordova?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

As per my exprience you can use default `ionic` pre-define **Return key** type as per below detail.

[image]

So by adding `type` property you will get all above type keyboard and return key name.

But for specific `iOS` type return keys and its action you need to follow below `GIT` thread where they implemented custom solution for this as there is no default support in `ionic` framework.

**GIT discussion Ref Link :** https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/54

**Stack Link for ref :** [How to handle "Go"/"Enter" keyboard button Ionic2 <ion-input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730477/how-to-handle-go-enter-keyboard-button-ionic2-ion-input)

Hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.